# Irrregular Puzzle Piece matching issue

Tags: ios

I am working on a jigsaw puzzle app. that have irregular pieces.I have done cut out that piece by shading and crop. Now  i make a array of dictionary witch have each piece left,right,top,bottom index.that's why i am able to recognize each piece. But problem is that when i recognize 2 piece. It must be combine in to one piece.then a new view  is create for that combine piece.now problem start to me How to recognize that combine piece to other pieces. Can any body help me to solve out that problem Or any right idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of your puzzle board as a Square grid of cells, where each piece once place will represent cell of a grid.

Now when you have created puzzle pieces you can store those pieces in an Array, in a sequential order  of there appearance in a grid.

You can represent your Grid as a single dimension array like below

```
suppose your puzzle is 4*4 than your one dimensional array will be of size 16

and you can pick up position of any piece at (m,n) in grid using below formula

index in array = m+(n*4) where m,n >=0 & m,n < 4
```

Than you can check the grid location of each piece corresponding to its array position to check if its at right location or not

Comment: Thanks, but each pieces are in scroll view.there we are drag them and ones right piece combine it will moveable to any location also.